# Javascript to create a zip file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jszip

I have an ionic app in which I need to create zip of some files on the device and send them to node server.

I am trying to use JSZip [http://stuk.github.io/jszip/] to create a zip of the files on the device. I have complete path of each of the files which is send to the function in filesList array.

```
 // complete path of all the files that need to be zipped is in filesList array
    // Eg., file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BACCA40A-56C4-4BE5-8C5D-1576960BD14B/Library/NoCloud/1473447800255.zip
      var zipFiles = function(filesList) {
                var uniqueFilename = Date.now();
                var zip = new JSZip();
                // create a zip with a unique name
                var zipFolder = zip.folder(uniqueFilename);
                //add files to the zip
                filesList.forEach(function(file) {
                   zipFolder.file(file);    
                })
var promise = null;
            if (JSZip.support.uint8array) {
              promise = zipFolder.generateAsync({type : "uint8array"});
              return promise;
            } else {
              promise = zipFolder.generateAsync({type : "string"});
              return promise;
            } 

       }
```

then in the calling function

```
myAPI.zipFiles(docList)
               .then(function(result) {
                   console.log('Zip created '+JSON.stringify(result)); 
               .catch(function(error) {
                 console.log('Error while creating zip '+error);
               });
```

I would like to create a zip in memory (don't need to save it on the device) and send it to node.

The code above is resulting in an empty zip even though filesList array has 5 files and the path to those files is also valid.

Documentation says that data returned by generateAsync method is Uint8Array. Do I need to do something to convert this to a zip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple JSZip - Create Zip File From Existing Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957032/simple-jszip-create-zip-file-from-existing-images)

Comment: I have done what the other post says - zipFolder.file(file); but that does not do the trick. I think the way zip file is generated in both these cases is different. In the other example, a single file is getting fetched and added to a zip. In my code, I first create a zip file and then add multiple files to it.